# Need a regular expression for match a 'url' in 'img' tag

Tags: ruby, regex

I have a string in ruby, in which I have text like give below.

```
ink = "<a href=\"https://www.abc.gov/asd/asdfg/bill/bill-a\">H.R.11461</a>"
ink = "<a href=\"https://www.abc.gov/asd/asdfg/bill/bill-b\">H.R.11461</a>"
ink = "<img class='image-small' src=\"https://www.abc.gov/asd/asdfg/bill/bill-a\">"
ink = "<img class='image-large' src=\"https://www.abc.gov/asd/asdfg/bill/bill-b\" id='image'>"
ink = "<iframe class='ifram' src=\"http://www.xyzabc.com\"></iframe>"
ink = "<iframe src=\"http://www.xyzabc.com\" id='fram-1'></iframe>"
```

I want to match only source URL of image, means value scr attribute of `img` tag by regular expression.

Output should be like,

```
https://www.abc.gov/asd/asdfg/bill/bill-a
https://www.abc.gov/asd/asdfg/bill/bill-b
```

Is there any way to get expected output by regex in ruby?

Comment: You shouldn't use a regexp to parse html (see [this answer to understand why](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/2483313)). Use a XML and HTML library like [Nokogiri](http://www.nokogiri.org/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an expression like this one:
`<img.*?src=\\"(.+?)\\"`

You'll need to use the global modifier for the regex to get all matches on several tags.
If you are testing one string at a time, it shouldn't be necessary.

[Example at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/qS6jN2/1)